# mysql C ssl connection what cipher to use?

Tags: mysql, c, security, ssl, encryption

Hello i am using C to connect to a mysql database. The database runs on an server which runs apache. I already have a working connection from my device to the server and the mysql database. Now I have to encrypt the mysql data stream by using ssl.

I found in the mysql C API the function mysql_set_ssl(). I have found some examples for the function but I am a bit confused, because in some examples there is the cipher set NULL and some other have a cipher.

My question is what is the difference between the them and what cipher should I use?

Comment: Can you edit your question and clearify as to how you connect to the database? 'The database runs on an apache.' seems to indicate you have some kind of http access to it rather than a direct connection?

Comment: is it more clearly now? the connection itself is already ok and I use the C library for mysql if this also helps. The main problem I have is how the ssl encryption is established. I read in the API that the cipher which I am asking for is used for encryption, but more information about the cipher I didn't really found. So I looked for examples about it and in some I saw that the cipher was NULL and some other had something like "DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA" inside. So this why I am confused what to use

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-ssl-set.html):

> - `cipher` is a list of permissible ciphers to use for SSL encryption.
>
> Any unused SSL parameters may be given as `NULL`.

This would suggest that passing `NULL` as the ciphers means 'just use any cipher'. If you would like to specify the allowed ciphers (for example because some are not safe to use), you may pass the list of permitted ciphers. Information on what they might be can be [obtained here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/ciphers.html).

Also, as more documentation states:

> To determine which ciphers a given server supports, use the following statement to check the value of the Ssl_cipher_list status variable:
>
> ```
> SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher_list';
> ```

The same doc also says you can

> ```
> SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';
> ```

to see if the connection is encypted and how. You may try `NULL` as an argument and see if that automatically selects the strongest common available cipher as I suspect it to do.